# How to change images while focusing or focusing so that user know which is selected?

Tags: jquery-mobile

Can you please tell me how to add focus and unfocused image in jQuery Mobile. I add one button. I need to change images in think? `onfocus` or at `unfocus` so that it user can easily identify .Which button is selected or which button is unselected .If i have two button I think I need to check which button is selected or which button is unselected?

Can you please tell how to do this task?

I use like this

```
<div class="ui-block-c" style="margin-left: 5px;">
        <a href="#" data-role="button" data-corners="false"  data-inline="true" class="next_h" id="next">Next</a>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-block-d" style="margin-left: 30px;">
        <a href="#" data-role="button" data-corners="false" data-inline="true" class="previous_h" id="prev">Previous</a>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simple use :hover to animate hover.

Or add a class as shown below for focusin and focusout events;

Using CSS and jQuery;

```
$("a").focusin(function(){
  $(this).addClass("selected");
});

$("a").focusout(function(){
  $(this).removeClass("selected");
});
```

And define a new CSS rule;

```
.selected {
   (add your selected picture as a background or another effect)
}
```

If you want separate background pictures;

```
.selected .next_h {
   (add your selected picture as a background or another effect)
}
.selected .prev_h {
   (add your selected picture as a background or another effect)
}
```

Comment: but i need to change images..i have two images..?

Comment: resetAll function will reset all buttons and click event's callback function will only change  the clicked one.

Comment: mean ..!! i need to change images on fucus and unfocus

Comment: focusin and focusout events are what u r looking for i guess; edited the answer to answer this.